# Heuristics for choosing CNN kernel size and channel count for each layer

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I want to build a CNN in PyTorch for identifying certain features. I have seen a lot of posts about what these parameters do, but I have not seen one about the order which they should be in when building a deep CNN. Do you start with a big kernel and high channel count and shrink those as you move through the  layers? Or is there some other order and are there other parameters that need to change? I have the feeling that you start with a small kernel and you go bigger so the network recognises bigger features at the end of the network, but this is purely based on my own intuition and I have no idea what works best.

Comment: There really aren't any good heuristics for this, partially because this type of questions is what deep  learning helps you avoid. Generally, it's best to start small and simple. The smallest kernel, the least amount of channels, the least amount of layers and increase as needed. Then, increasing depth is much better than adding channels and adding residual connections is also a good idea. 

However, it's even better to start with existing architectures, of which many are available through torchvision for example